# When we need to remove constness of a variable , usage example?

Tags: c++

Hello I'm new to c++ I've read that if I've a const variable I can remove its constness and update the variable as I please but in general it defeata the purpose of const . Can someone explain why one would ever make something const to remove its constness later?

Comment: You should remove the `const`-ness when you KNOW the variable will NOT be modified.  Usually for C APIs that don't have a notion of `const`-ness, even though they don't modify the object (which is often an array of `char`, but could be a `struct`).

Comment: when you hold a constant reference, it means that you cannot modify the object through that reference, it does not imply that the object is const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you should not do it, but some time you are stuck with a third party library which expects a char* ,but in your implementation you have the field marked as const , then you need to temporarily cast away the constness then make the function call.